# How to save text temporary in textfield?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, save

I have a little problem, when I have text put in a UITextfield in view controller A and I go to an other view controller and then i go back to view controller A the text in the textfield had disappear.

Is there a way to save the text temporary in the textfield? So the text won't disappear when you go to an other view controller.

Comment: is your uitextfield weak?

Comment: no my UITextfield is Strong

Comment: how are you going to another view? can you post your code going another view? and how are you back to current view?

Comment: KAREEM MAHAMMED are right, it's strange that the text disappear, i think you are using a big memory in the B view, are you pushing a viewcontroller that uses camera?

Comment: I saw down there, most of them using Global strings **DONT DO THAT**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you navigate the page at that time save the data in NSUserDefaults .

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:textfield.text forKey:@"textfield value"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

and re assign the textfield value in `viewWillAppear` method.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   textfield.text= [defaults  valueForKey:@"textfield value"];
```

or

other wise take an global string and assign the string value to textFiled and Vice Versa.

Comment: While this will allow you to retrieve the saved value from any where throughout the app, this might not fix the underline problem.  The OP did state "i go back to view controller A the text in the textfield had disappear"

Answer (score 1):

Use UINavigationController. You can then add a screen to navigation stack using pushViewController and remove a screen from stack using popViewController. Your contents in textfield will be preserved when you come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global variable and store text in that global variable.

To achieve this you can user .pch file of `AppDelegate` file to manage global variable.

Or you can user `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are number of methods. If you want the text to be visible only when the app is running then save the text in a global `NSString` and add it to the `UITextfield` in your `viewWillAppear` method.

Your you can set a property as global too, where you can add declare the string in your AppDelgate or in a global singleton class.

If you want to save the variable/string then use `NSSUserDefaults`