# Passing data from detail to master in ios6

Tags: xcode, ios6, master-detail

I'm making an application with xcode, and I have a trouble with passing data between views.
I want to set in detail view, a date of a calendar. Then when I go back to the master view I want to see the events in the selected date, but I don`t know how I make it.
Can you help me?

Comment: you can to using global array which is defined in appDelegate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633773/how-to-save-text-temporary-in-textfield/15633878#15633878

Comment: Ok, it's good way to make this!! thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two most common approaches:

1) use unwind segue if you're using storyboard in the project. The approach is perfectly discussed  here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CreatingAddView/CreatingAddView.html

2) use delegate pattern. I found the below tutorial quite useful when I had started to learn delegation:

http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can communicate between 2 class

```
ViewController *dvController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
// ViewController is controler where you want to send date from particular controler we are making object of ViewController where you want to send data
    dvController.selectedBirthdate = selectedbirthdate;
    dvController.selectedName = selectedname;
    //you are sending data in above two lines just imagine you are sending string




  [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
  //then pushviewcontroller and there you go
  [dvController release];
```

simple as that

there is another way to comunicate between 2 classes is that app delegate make object of you app delegate and then assing what you want to particular varible of app delegate and then you can use that variable anywhere in project

create app delegate object like this

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//and then access the variable by appDelegate.variable
```

if you are using storyboard then  you can use prepareForSegue like below

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:...]) {
        MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.myProperty1 = ...;
        controller.myProperty2 = ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do the same, but I have a segue from master to detail, and when I make another fron detail to master, crash

Comment: you dont need to make another from detail to master check documentation how navigation works

Comment: read this whole and try to undertand it and problem is solved then http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: dont use NSUserDefault its used only for storing so small things like user preference

Comment: if my things is usefull then dont forget to vote up and accept answer :))

Comment: Friend, I want to pass data from detail to master, because i change data in detail and i want to show data changed. I know how can i pass data beetween views but if i have a segue from master to detail, how can in pass data in the other way??

Comment: there is perpareforsegue method if you are using storyboard i have updated answer and why you are using words like detail and master? is that tableview and detailview?

Comment: yes, is tableview and detailview. I`m going to use delegate pattern

Comment: best of luck :) and sorry i wasnt help full

Comment: lewandowski made 4 goals against real merdrit did you see football?